# Is there a function to only send a message if it matches the complete sentence?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently using this code to find the trigger word "apy" in a sentence. However, it is spamming the Discord since "apy" comes up a lot.

I am looking for a solution to only send a message if it matches a sentence. For example:

Someone writes: `Why did the apy go down?`
bot replies: `The APY was removed to focus on sustainability and growth.`

My code I'm using now is:

```
if "apy" in msg.content.split():
    await channel.send("The APY was removed to focus on sustainability and growth.")
```

Comment: Then why not just do `if "Why did the apy go down" in msg.content:`?

Comment: When should the bot not send a message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
if msg.content.lower() == "why did the apy go down?":
    await channel.send("The APY was removed to focus on sustainability and growth.")
```

or if you want to have multiple sentences that can trigger:

```py
messages_list = ["question 1", "question 2"]
# ...
if msg.content.lower() in messages_list:
    await channel.send("The APY was removed to focus on sustainability and growth.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex, to match even more specific strings

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("why did the apy go down")

if re.match(pattern, msg.content.lower()):
     await channel.send("The APY was removed to focus on sustainability and growth.")
```

Comment: You are not using any of the regex's benefits here so it's just an overkill

Comment: You are right, but this approach is quite flexible if OP _does_ want to add some more intricate patterns